# Error oracle al consultar coordenadas sdo_geometry

Tags: oracle

vereis, estoy realizando una consulta a la base de datos desde mi programa hecho en c#, la consulta es la siguiente(un ejemplo que debería ser valido):

```
 (select  ad.ordem_aa ordem_aa, mfx.sequencia seq, mfx.nrnac nacfx, ad.nomep
  as area, mfx.nrint int, mfx.nome nomefx,  mfx.localp localmfx, 
 c.coord1_univ as lat, c.coord2_univ as lon, c.coord1 lat1, c.coord2 
 lon1,e.id_blob idblob, mfx.alcances alcfx, mfx.altitudes altitfx, 
 mfx.carateristicas carfx, mfx.obs obsfx, e.obs1 obs, e.obs2 obs2, e.colour 
 colour from marcasfixas mfx, areasadmins ad, locuss l, coords c, estruturas 
 , coords_aux ca where  ad.id_aa = l.area_id_aa and l.id_loc = mfx.lc_id_loc 
 (+)  and l.id_loc = c.lc_id_loc and l.id_loc = ca.lc_id_loc and c.datafinal 
 is null and ca.datafinal is null and mfx.id_mfx = e.mfx_id_mfx (+) and 
 mfx.estado = '1'  and sdo_inside(CA.geomuniv, 
 Sdo_Geometry(2003,null,null,Sdo_Elem_Info_Array(1,1003,3),Sdo_Ordinate_ARRAY(-9.
 12999989941696,38.411666627551,-9.06500011734690,38.45000016763840)))='true' ) 
 union (select ad.ordem_aa ordem_aa, mfl.sequencia seq, mfl.nrnac nacfx, 
 ad.nomep as area, Decode(Mfl.Nrint, Null, '0', Mfl.Nrint) Int, mfl.nome 
 nomefx,  '1' localmfx, mfl.id_blob idBlob, c.coord1_univ as lat, 
 c.coord2_univ as lon, c.coord1 lat1, c.coord2 lon2, mfl.alcances alcfx, 
 mfl.altitudes altitfx, mfl.carateristicas carfx, mfl.obs obsfx, mfl.obs1 
 obs, mfl.obs2 obs2 ,mfl.colour  from marcasflutuantes mfl, areasadmins ad, 
 locuss l, coords c, coords_aux ca where  ad.id_aa = l.area_id_aa and 
 l.id_loc = mfl.lc_id_loc (+)  and l.id_loc = c.lc_id_loc and l.id_loc = 
 ca.lc_id_loc and c.datafinal is null and ca.datafinal is null and 
 mfl.estado = '1'  and sdo_inside(CA.geomuniv, 
 Sdo_Geometry(2003,null,null,Sdo_Elem_Info_Array(1,1003,3),Sdo_Ordinate_ARRAY(-9.
 12999989941696,38.411666627551,-9.06500011734690,38.45000016763840)))='true' );
```

Bien, la parte interesante reside en:
`Sdo_Geometry(2003,null,null,Sdo_Elem_Info_Array(1,1003,3),Sdo_Ordinate_ARRAY(-9 12999989941696,38.411666627551,-9.06500011734690,38.45000016763840)))='true' );`

ya que el error que salta es el siguiente :

```
 ORA-29902: error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine
 ORA-13207: incorrect use of the [SDO_INSIDE] operator
 ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I", line 369
 29902. 00000 -  "error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine"
 *Cause:    The execution of ODCIIndexStart routine caused an error.
 *Action:   Examine the error messages produced by the indextype code and
            take appropriate action.
```

Llevo horas mirando documentacion de constructores de `Sdo_geometry()`, `sdo_elemen_info_array()` y `sdo_ordinate_array` y no encuentro donde estoy cometiendo el error.

Necesito ayuda :C

Comment: Este error no parece tener nada que ver con c#. Yo quitaría el tag.

Comment: es mas ni siquiera es sql es oracle puro

Comment: ya esta, esq el trabajo es en c# y uso sqlDeveloper, por eso habia puesto los tags. Ya los he modificado @Pikoh